I accidentally deleted "%ProgramData%\Package Cache” - What can I do?
I accidentally deleted %ProgramData%\Package Cache and can't properly uninstall programs that use an .msi installer, or install new programs.
I am stuck as I don't know what to do - how do I fix this?

Apparently there are a few options available, perhaps the easiest one to try first would be the Your PC isn't working well and you recently installed an app choice on Microsoft's website.

At the worst, download Windows 11 ISO and reinstall, keeping software and files. For apps added through Microsoft Store, that likely will be restored from MS. As MSI installers, most don't use the cache. However, restoring from the last full drive image is far more reliable and far easier.

@JW0914 I've edited my question to specify which path

Have you tried restoring it from the Recyle Bin or recovering with TestDisk? If not, creating directory %ProgramData\Package Cache should resolve not being able to install new programs. A reinstall of Windows, nor a Repair Install, will resolve the overarching issue AFAIK since the only way to fix %ProgramData%\Package Cache being permanently deleted would be to reinstall all software that's been installed since it stores the MSI uninstaller and any uninstaller files for the .msi (contents of mine)

(Cont'd...) The reason installers are failing is likely because they expect %ProgramData%\Package Cache to exist and likely don't have a create command for that directory in their installer. If unable to restore %ProgramData\Package Cache, and re-creating the directory does not resolve being able to install new programs, a Repair Install would be worth a shot, but is unlikely to fix since %ProgramData\Package Cache doesn't exist by default on a new Windows install (open an install ISO's sources\install.esd in 7zip, browsing to <1|6>\ProgramData)

Do you run visual studio? "%ProgramData%\Package Cache" is related to it and its libs. On other hand programs uninstall paths/commands are in registry. Can you please also confirm that "Windows installer" is running in your "Services"(should be running and set to Automatic)?

@Danijel It's used by way more than Visual Studio, see the link in my previous comment. If a program uses an .msi uninstaller and %ProgramData%\Package Cache is deleted and not recoverable, those programs can't be uninstalled without the .msi installer - this has zero to do with the Registry. The only way to remove such programs is either (1) reinstall the program, which recreates the deleted uninstaller files; or (2) a cleaner program for each individual program is required, which removes all installed files the way an installer would, but differently.

@JW0914, (0 and 1)true, or yes, (2) do you rly suggest "cleaner program" like cc? where is (3)? you didnt say anything about services? you oughta stop doing that :)

@Danijel I would never recommend using any type of cleaner program since they usually create more problems than they solve, especially when it comes to the Registry - I was referring to an individual cleaner program that's specific to each installed program which can't be uninstalled (for example, Comodo offers a cleaner program for all its software), as these programs will manually stop any services to be uninstalled, remove all required files, drivers, Registry keys, etc; however, my preferred solution, if it was me, would be to simply reinstall all currently installed software.

This begs the question: exactly how did you "accidentally" delete an important system folder like that?

C:\ProgramData\Package Cache Does exist...


Run the uninstall using something like BulkCrap Uninstall or Revo


When something like this pops up, keep note of its UUID {4534F2ED-1616-434D-98A6-0DA358DCD466} for example

Then hit cancel, its okay, let it error out.

Remove the leftovers using BC or Revo

Go to regedit and navigate to


Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products


Search for the UUID you copied (ctrl+f)

Delete its parent key
Make sure to close regedit
Run the uninstaller again
If it shows another error, go back to step 1




You can always left-click on shortcuts, open file location, and look for an uninstaller.exe.
also, you can download an installer for the program most of the time it will supply an option to repair modify or uninstall the program.

This question kinda presupposes that you cannot do this. An msi installer may begin running with a missing installer cache, but it will fail.

The answer of @Advik is absolutely wonderful but it did not work completely for me.
I deleted %ProgramData%\Package Cache as well and none of my Windows Update would get done.
In those case, you can :

Manually download the update

Simply by getting the failed update code (Example used; KB5039844).

Execute the updates .exe

Wait for the fail point. If the installer tells you that a package cannot be located, note the path of the Use source and the name of the package and click cancel then wait for the setup to display Setup Failed, you will then have an option to open the log file, you're not obligated to open it.
If you go in the logs, look for the first instance of Error 0, you'll normally find a line with an error code like this Error 0x80070003. Around that, the error should mention the path of a Package Cache .exe or .msi (in our case C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{b0e8183d-9440-42a3-ab2d-874ffc706cd4}\dotnet-sdk-7.0.118-win-x64.exe). If you attempt to go to that directory, it should not exist (cause you deleted it).

Install missing Package Cache

Simply lookup for the .exe that's missing online (here, dotnet-sdk-7.0.118-win-x64.exe which is available on Microsoft's download page of .NET 7.0 Version 7.0.18 under SDK) and download it. Then, create the Package Cache path that's missing (here, C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{b0e8183d-9440-42a3-ab2d-874ffc706cd4}\) and put the downloaded .exe in the folder (here, sdk-7.0.118-win-x64.exe).
PLEASE NOTE : some .exe have to be ran and not put in the Package Cache folder (for example, for dotnet-host-7.0.18-win-x64.msi and other .msi, you will need to run the .exe to install the .msi`)

Retry executing the updates .exe

Run the .exe of the Windows update you downloaded at the first step (here, KB5039844's .exe). If you still get an error (here, C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{EE5EB03B-D65C-4991-848E-2C6E024326DB}v56.80.15184\dotnet-host-7.0.20-win-x64.msi still missing), simply repeat the steps until all the necessary Package Cache are installed.

Bonuses and info

Sometimes, installers are still running in background. Make sure to kill those trough the Task Manager.
This is not a 100%, universal solution. Sometimes, like for KB5039844, it is too tedious. It worked for me on KB5041080.
Courage and patience to you, whoever you are.
